# Hibernate hql/sql join using between dates not filtering properly

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I hope someone can help me understand why the following is occurring. I'm using hibernate and HQL but the results are the same across sqlserver or hsqldb with the generated sql from hibernate - my dates are not filtering for my JOINed table.

The crux of the problem is a hql query that has multiple joins where one of the joins I want to filter based on a date filter. The results are incorrectly including data outside my date range. So for example if the startMonthAndYear and endMonthAndYear are 01/2015 and 12/2015 I'm seeing results (from saAllocationList) outside that range (for example in 01/2010).

HQL has the limitation where I can't perform a subquery in the JOIN itself, which is what I have been told will work. My problem is it seems like each way I've written SHOULD be doing the same thing .. but of course I'm not understanding something b/c none of them filter the dates like I want.

My initial HQL attempts to filter in the WHERE clause.

```sql
SELECT sa 
FROM StaffingAssignment sa 
    INNER JOIN sa.workGroup wg
    LEFT JOIN sa.positionRole pr
    INNER JOIN sa.employee em
    INNER JOIN sa.sAAllocationList sal
WHERE wg.programWorkGroupID = :id
    AND sa.sAAllocationPK.dateUnit BETWEEN :startMonthAndYear AND :endMonthAndYear
```

The above generates to the following sql:

```sql
select staffingas0_.ID as ID1_6_, (trimmed by me) from StaffingAllocation staffingas0_ 
inner join WorkGroup workgroup1_ on staffingas0_.WorkGroupID=workgroup1_.ID 
left outer join PositionRole positionro2_ on staffingas0_.PositionRoleID=positionro2_.ID 
inner join Employee employeeex3_ on staffingas0_.EmployeeID=employeeex3_.ID 
inner join SAAllocation saallocati4_ on staffingas0_.ID=saallocati4_.SAID 
    where workgroup1_.ProgramWorkGroupID=? and (saallocati4_.DateUnit between ? and ?)
```

I've rewritten the hsql in a few different ways:

With a subquery in the where clause to attempt to get a list of ids to load:

```sql
SELECT sa 
FROM StaffingAssignment sa
  INNER JOIN sa.sAAllocationList
  INNER JOIN sa.workGroup wg
  LEFT JOIN sa.positionRole pr
  INNER JOIN sa.employee em
WHERE wg.programWorkGroupID = :id AND sa.id IN 
                      (SELECT saa.staffingAllocation.id
                      FROM SAAllocation saa
                      WHERE saa.sAAllocationPK.dateUnit 
                          BETWEEN :startMonthAndYear AND :endMonthAndYear)
```

Generates the following sql:

```sql
select staffingas0_.ID as ID1_6_, (trimmed by me) from StaffingAllocation staffingas0_ 
inner join SAAllocation saallocati1_ on staffingas0_.ID=saallocati1_.SAID 
inner join WorkGroup workgroup2_ on staffingas0_.WorkGroupID=workgroup2_.ID 
left outer join PositionRole positionro3_ on staffingas0_.PositionRoleID=positionro3_.ID 
inner join Employee employeeex4_ on staffingas0_.EmployeeID=employeeex4_.ID 
where workgroup2_.ProgramWorkGroupID=? and (staffingas0_.ID in (select saallocati5_.SAID from SAAllocation saallocati5_ where saallocati5_.DateUnit between ? and ?))
```

with the `WITH` keyword in HQL to try to do the filter in the JOIN itself:

```sql
SELECT sa
FROM StaffingAssignment sa
    INNER JOIN sa.sAAllocationList sal WITH sal.sAAllocationPK.dateUnit BETWEEN 
        :startMonthAndYear AND :endMonthAndYear
    INNER JOIN sa.workGroup wg
    LEFT JOIN sa.positionRole pr
    INNER JOIN sa.employee em
WHERE wg.programWorkGroupID = :id
```

Generates the following sql:

```sql
select staffingas0_.ID as ID1_6_, (trimmed by me) from StaffingAllocation staffingas0_ 
inner join SAAllocation saallocati1_ on staffingas0_.ID=saallocati1_.SAID and (saallocati1_.DateUnit between ? and ?) 
inner join WorkGroup workgroup2_ on staffingas0_.WorkGroupID=workgroup2_.ID 
left outer join PositionRole positionro3_ on staffingas0_.PositionRoleID=positionro3_.ID 
inner join Employee employeeex4_ on staffingas0_.EmployeeID=employeeex4_.ID 
where workgroup2_.ProgramWorkGroupID=?
```

But everything returns the same results (include the dates for outside the range I'm trying to filter on).

Thanks for reading, if there's any more information I can include that would help let me know this has been days of fiddling with nothing to show and I know it's b/c I'm not understanding the SQL well enough. Thanks!

EDIT:

I added a sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8348d/2 unfortunately the sqlfiddle does the RIGHT thing (i.e. filters out the data from 2010). can anyone make it do the WRONG thing and then explain to me why?

Comment: You might want to try to cast those date parameters explicitly to dates in the query...

Comment: This would be easier to analyse if you included table definitions and example data, perhaps some results too. For example, I don't know what values you have in `dateUnit`, so how can I tell if they should or shouldn't be included? It could be `CHAR(7)` with values like `'01/2010'` for all I know.

Comment: Also class definitions would be nice ;-) Can, just for a test remove left join part from query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, although it left me questioning my understanding about JOINs in hibernate. This blog explains the solution well:
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/04/objects-vs-data-and-filtering-join.html

I needed to use a JOIN FETCH:

```
SELECT sa 
FROM StaffingAssignment sa 
    INNER JOIN sa.workGroup wg
    LEFT JOIN sa.positionRole pr
    INNER JOIN sa.employee em
    INNER JOIN FETCH sa.sAAllocationList sal
WHERE wg.programWorkGroupID = :id
    AND sa.sAAllocationPK.dateUnit BETWEEN :startMonthAndYear AND :endMonthAndYear
```

By using the JOIN FETCH it forces hibernate to perform the qualifier as part of the fetch. This is essentially an EAGER loading of the collection JOINed in WITH the qualifier applied. What my query was doing (I think) was just loading in the ids of the qualified JOINed rows, but when I accessed the collection it loaded the entire collection (LAZILY) and that was throwing me off until I noticed the lazy loading taking place.

HOWEVER: As the blog cautions - if using second-level cache it puts the cache at risk b/c when you qualify the JOIN you've now put the values into cache in a way that's really inconsistent with the database. In order to mediate this you can further tell hibernate to not put things in the cache by setting:

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "BYPASS");
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", "BYPASS");
```

I'm not using second level cache and I don't think I can do the above with HQL so I'm not worrying about this detail.

This has made me curious about what a JOIN is doing, since I thought it WAS avoiding the N+1 problem, but maybe it's just loading some ids in to avoid having to do database work to determine the ids to load, but the object itself isn't loaded yet. That's a topic for another question/research though. Thanks for those that took time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with C# and NHibernate.

What data type is your time column in the database (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`)? The data type in your query must be the same as in the database. Otherwise the `WHERE` clause will not apply correctly.

Comment: in the database the type is a DateTime. in my hibernate code the type is a java.util.Date. those 2 types should match, i would think.

my unit tests are attempting to filter an outlier from 2010 .. whereas the data included is from 01/2015-12/2015. I did this on purpose just to ensure there wasn't any weird midnight rollover logic or anything present.